# Is there a way enforce use of a custom content type for drag&drop and for File/New Folder button?

Tags: 2013, drag-and-drop, custom-content-type

I created a custom content type called PIN Folder. The content type has 3 attributes - title (required), ms (optional), and comment (optional). In my library I created a default view for PIN Folders which use this content type. As desired, now when I add folders through the File/New Document/PIN Folder button, a folder is created with the PIN Folder attributes.

The problem is that when I drag/drop folders via the Explorer view, or add a folder using the File/New Folder button, the only attribute applied is title.  Based on this, my assumption is that drag/drop and New Folder use the standard folder content type rather than my custom content type.

There are going to be numerous picture libraries with hundreds of PIN folders in each library, so drag/drop is the best method for initial creation for the library content.

Is there a way **without code** to enforce use of my folder custom content type when dragging/dropping or using New Folder? (I do have SP Designer.)

Note:  I considered creating a subsite and changing the default folder content type for that subsite.  Would that be viable?

Comment: what version of sharepoint are you using (on prem, which versioin or online)

Comment: On prem.  SP 2013.  
I needed to remove the original default content type.  Was able to remove them via SP Designer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing it without code.

There is a way of making custom folder a default one:

1. Create a new custom folder content type (inherit from folder)
2. Add that folder to the library.
3. Remove the default folder from the library (use Sharepoint Manager, or PS http://get-spscripts.com/2010/11/add-and-remove-site-content-types-from.html
4. Now the custom folder type should be default, even if you create folders from the explorer view via WebDAV but it will not give  you the option to fill in the custom metadata.

I think in your case best approach would be to write some PowerShell to migrate that content.